# SSRS set year variables per record

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I need help to create a code to have it display years specified.

User defines years to report:  `Year1 Year2 Year3`

```
ProductID   Year1 data
            Year2 data
            Year3 data
```

where even if year 2 has no data like below

```
ProductID   Year1 data
            Year2 
            Year3 data
```

My current code will show all data that fit the criteria, but will not show Year2 due to no data.

My current code is

```
select 
    sales.ProductID, Sales.Trans_Year, Sum(salesQTY) as QTY
from 
    (select ProductID, Year(Trans_dt) as Trans_Year, salesQTY
     from salestable) sales
group by 
    sales.ProductID, Sales.Trans_Year
```

My code is inefficient but I did the select twice so that it would group the year on transdate, if any new to make it better would much appreciated.

Hoping to get help to have the following result.

```
ProductID   Year1 QTY
ProductID   Year2 
ProductID   Year3 QTY
```

Thank you

Comment: outer join a cte/help table that returns all wanted years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the years from your table and cross join them to the products to get a matrix of all years and products. The CROSS JOIN will make a record for each year for each product - regardless if the product was sold in that year.

Then LEFT JOIN your sales total. Using a LEFT JOIN will allow the year and product ID from the SALES_YEAR and SALES subqueries to show even if there's none of a product sold in that year.

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ProductID, YEARS.SALES_YEAR, SALES.TOTAL_SALES
FROM (
    SELECT ProductID 
    FROM salestable 
    GROUP BY ProductID
     ) AS PRODUCTS 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(Trans_dt) AS SALES_YEAR 
    FROM salestable 
    WHERE YEAR(Trans_dt) IN @YEARS 
     ) AS YEARS 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ProductID, Year(Trans_dt) as Trans_Year, SUM(salesQTY) AS TOTAL_SALES
    FROM salestable
    GROUP BY Year(Trans_dt)
    ) SALES ON SALES.Trans_Year = YEARS.SALES_YEAR AND SALES.ProductID = PRODUCTS.ProductID
```

Note that this assumes that you sold **something** every year selected. If the user enter 1905 for the year and there's no data for 1905, that year wouldn't appear. That shouldn't really be an issue though.

Comment: Also note that you can GROUP BY YEAR(Trans_dt) (or most any function) so you didn't need the subquery.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. didn't know why I have not thought of that. I never used cross join before, this will indeed a good time to use it.

Comment: @user2324065 - thanks. I did just notice I left the ON clause on that CROSS JOIN that would cause an error. I have removed it. Originally it was an `INNER JOIN ON 1 = 1` which actually works the same as the CROSS JOIN.